# Keras ResNet50 model for Melanoma prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, resnet

Below is my professor's code to implement Keras ResNet50.

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(150, 150,3))

Y_train = []
X_train = []

label = 0
# 2 for loop, 1 for classes and 1 for images in the class
for i in os.listdir(train_path): #for class
  img_path = train_path + "/" + i + "/" 
  img_num = 0
  for file in os.listdir(img_path): # for images
    img_path1 = img_path+"/"+file
    img=cv2.imread(img_path1)
    img=cv2.resize(img,(150,150))
    img = image.img_to_array(img) 
    img = resnet50.preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(img.copy(), axis=0))
    img = model.predict(img)
    X_train.append(img.flatten())        
    Y_train.append(label)
  label = label+1


Y_test = []
X_test = []

label = 0
for i in os.listdir(test_path):
  path = test_path + "/" + i + "/" 
  img_num = 0
  for file in os.listdir(img_path):
    img_path1 = img_path+"/"+file
    img=cv2.imread(img_path1)
    img=cv2.resize(img,(150,150))
    img = image.img_to_array(img) 
    img = resnet50.preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(img.copy(), axis=0))
    img = model.predict(img)
    X_test.append(img.flatten()/255) 
    Y_test.append(label)
  label = label+1

model = linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,Y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test,pred)
print((cm[0,0]+cm[1,1])/(sum(sum(cm))))
```

I asked my professor about why there are "double prediction", as in the line `img = model.predict(img)` and LogReg is implemented after that. He explained that `img = model.predict(img)` is to embed the image, not provide prediction. However when I looked up to online material they all said model.predict is to predict the image output.

So how should I understand the line `model.predict(img)` in this case?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it without the "img = model.predict(img)".

Comment: model.predict just makes predictions using your model, so it all depends what the model outputs, this concept can have multiple valid meanings depending on the model.

Comment: @Sivadithiyan I tried, it could still run but the accuracy based on the confusion matrix is lower